# visual studio 2013, could not complete the action

Tags: visual-studio

I have visual studio 2013 with the latest update(5). But every time if I try to create a webform project I get the warning: could not complete the action. See the picture. Ofcourse I searched first the internet for gettting the solution, to get rid of that annoying warning. But untill now no results. So maybe here someone have the golden tip, to get rid of the warning.

Thank you!!

[image]

And this warning I get only when I stand on a *.aspx page. So if I stand on a *.aspx.cs file I dont get the warning.

Comment: Have you repaired VS?

Comment: Are you saying that you already had or that you did so after my advice and it's now working?

Comment: Having the same issue and I've tried the repair option and it had no effect.  I also tried updating to the most recent update (update 5) which did not help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved now :). I just installed a other version of Visual studio 2013 with update 2 afterwards I installed update 5 and now everything works like a sharm :)